# node js update a mongodb collection with stream data

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In one nodejs script, I am receiving data in stream in form of username and their scores. I want to perform some aggregate functions like count, max, min and store in a mongodb collection. Here is going to be my collection look like,

```
> db.UserScore.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cd99550dfe3371cb0e38449"),
        "UserName" : "FirstUser",
        "Count" : 48,
        "MinScore" : 30,
        "MaxScore" : 78,
        "AvgScore" : 45
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cd995e7f290f21cb07b545b"),
        "UserName" : "SecondUser",
        "Count" : 45,
        "MinScore" : 12,
        "MaxScore" : 88,
        "AvgScore" : 35
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cd99607f290f21cb07b545c"),
        "UserName" : "ThirdUser",
        "Count" : 51,
        "MinScore" : 29,
        "MaxScore" : 63,
        "AvgScore" : 44
}
.......
.......
....... many more user data.
```

I want to know the best possible approach to manage database collection with stream data. I can do it with db update with each entry received in stream data,

```
db.UserScore.update(
    {"UserName" : "FirstUser"},
    {$set: { 
            "Count" : 49,
            "MinScore" : 20,
            "MaxScore" : 82,
            "AvgScore" : 46
           }});
```

But I think, this will not be a good idea to update collection with each row received ans it may result a major performance issue or cpu intensive activity. Please suggest me some way to perform the same with better way.

I googled and found mongodb collection watch and change stream feature, but that is from db collection to node.js and i want from node.js to db collection first.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can queue multiple updates together and then use [bulkWrite](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) to send all of them in one query.